# How should I do this? (iOS plist editing and updating all controllers)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uinavigationcontroller, plist

I am making an app which basically presents data (from plist) to user in table form. I have a lot of controllers and the user basically navigates through these controller to get to an item after which a final detail display is shown.
At that last view, the user can add that to favorites.

The way that I am passing data to view controller is that I pass them specific data, so at the last view, if the user adds the item to favorites, I write that data to file. But how can I tell all my other controller that the data has updated? 
This is more of a design problem and I don't know where to go..I have some idea but I want to know what is the standard way of doing this...Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to be listening for events within multiple objects, take a look at `NSNotificationCenter`. You can simply subscribe to listen for notifications then post one once the data is updated.

[NSNotificationCenter Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)